# Angular - Async Server call is updating canvas context but canvas view is not updating

Tags: html, angular, asynchronous, html5-canvas

i have a Map component which can render points in 2d canvas

```
map.component.ts

export class ........
{
  @ViewChild('canvas') public canvas: ElementRef; 
  private context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;  
  private Mapcanvas: HTMLCanvasElement;

  @Input() data:any;

  ngAfterViewInit()
  { 
  this.Mapcanvas=this.canvas.nativeElement; 
  this.context=this.Mapcanvas.getContext('2d'); 
  }
  public redraw()
  {
  //it takes the data(specified as Input() property which consists of coordinates) 
  //and do some preprocessing on data
  // and render it using 
   //   for Each coordinate =>  this.context.fillRect(Coordinate.x,Coordinate.y,width,height); 

  } 
}
```

```
map.component.html

<canvas #canvas id='canvas' style='left:0px; top:0px;' custom='sd'>
    </canvas>
```

i am hosting this map component into another parent component

```
parent.component.html

<map #map id="map" [data]='data | async'> </map>
```

```
parent.component.ts

export class ........
{ 
public data: Observable<any[]>;
private _data: BehaviorSubject<any[]>; 

@ViewChild('map')  Map:MapComponent; 


constructor(private _remoteService: dataService) {  
  this._data = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  this.data = this._data.asObservable();  
  }

  async loadData()
  {
   this._data.next(await this._remoteService.RemoteFunction().toPromise());
  }  

}
```

```
 Sevice.ts


export class......
 {  
    RemoteFunction():any
    { 
          return  this._http.get(URL);   
    }

 }
```

The problem here is when i am loading parent component 
it is showing map.component without data.
the data is fetched properly from API and Received by map.component.

The canvas context is updated the only problem i am facing is view is not updating.

Note:
How i am identifying that canvas context is updated? 
i have some other functionality that are working as expected with data received from API.

I tried ChangeDetectorRef and NgZone also.

any hint any help is appreciated.